# questions about play framework 1.2.4 before production

Tags: memory, playframework, gzip, playframework-1.x

hey all i want to place my play application in production,

i have some question and things i am not fully understand,hope u can help me there.

1) when using cache(play memcache) with out a memcache server, its said in the documentation that a play will use the JVM heap, dose it mean that he is STILL using memcache but for a single application only (or something else. didnt sure i understand that)?

2) since i am on a shared server, i am still thinking how secure is it to use memcache daemon with other users hosting in the same machine, is there a way around this ?

3) i noticed in some places over the network, that play is using less memory then the allocated memory by java, how can i know how much memory i really need so i can limit the memory of a play instance (i know play should have a small footprint) ?
(i will run my play application using production mode)

4) i have and apache2 server in front of my play application, and i want to GZIP my java script and CSS files. should i GZIP on the apache2 of in my playframework what will be a best practice ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - In this case play use ehcache which is a java cache, not memcache. Memcache is useful when you have multiple nodes. If you have only one instance ehcache is enough

2 - I don't know, you better have to see memcache doc for this

3 - You can limit memory to 32 or 64 mb depending on your app by putting this setting in your application.conf file "jvm.memory= -Xms64M -Xmx64M". To know the exact memory used by your app you have to monitor it in production with tools like visualvm or simply by doing some play status from time to time to see the evolution

4 - gzip have to be done on apache side